# How to get file path of opened file in UWP Application?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I want to get path of opened file with FileOpenPicker in my UWP application. I have a OpenFile named method. OpenFile methods code:

```cs
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

StorageFile storageFile = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (storageFile != null)
{
    var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream()))
    {
        Document.Text = sReader.ReadToEnd();
        Document.IsSaved = true;
    }
}
```

What do I need to do get file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storageFile.Path` will give you the path to the file, if it has one (which it should in this case).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.path